# Access Nested JSON objects and their attributes Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am a new bie to angular and trying to learn it. 
I am trying to display user data from a webservice that I received as response.
here's the response

```
    {
    "Users": {
        "SearchTerm": "angularjs ra1",
        "ResultsPerPage": "20",
        "RecordStartNumber": "0",
        "TotalEstimatedResults": "6",
        "User": [{
            "WWID": "123456",
            "Email": "mary.p.wilson@yahoo.com",
            "BusinessTitle": "Project Manager",
            "Name": "Mary Wilson",
            "firstname": "Mary",
            "lastname": "Wilson",
            "idsid": "RAP"
        }, {
            "WWID": "1234567",
            "Email": "steve.r.smith@gmail.com",
            "BusinessTitle": "Quality Assurance",
            "Name": "Steve Smith",
            "firstname": "Steve",
            "lastname": "Smith",
            "idsid": "DRPRESTO"
        }, {
            "WWID": "12345678",
            "Email": "jon.jones@gmail.com",
            "BusinessTitle": "Chef",
            "Name": "Jon Jones",
            "firstname": "Jon",
            "lastname": "Jones",
            "idsid": "JJONES"
        }]
    }
}
```

MyScript.js

```
    var Application = angular.module('TestModule', []);
Application.controller('TestController', function ($scope,$http) {
    $scope.TestValue = "Hello World from Controller";
    $scope.Myfunc = function asdf() {
        $http.get('http://unifiedcollaborationprofile.gots.com/search/expert/data/v2/?apiKey=SECRET&listFromPersonNumber=0&numPeoplePerPage=20&query=angularjs+ra1&returnFriendlyResults=true').then(
            function (response) {
                $scope.users = [];
                angular.forEach(response.Users, function (value, key) {
                    $scope.users.push(value);
                });
            });
    };
});
```

Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestModule">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
{{2+3}}
<body>
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        {{2+3}}
        {{TestValue}}
        <input type="text" ng-model="TestValue" />
        <input type="button" value="Click Me To Get All Users!!!!" ng-click="Myfunc()" />
        <ul ng-repeat="k in users">
            <li>WWID:{{k.WWID}}  Email:{{k.Email}}  Name:{{k.Name}}  IDSID:{{k.idsid}}</li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/MyScripts/MyScript.js"></script>
```

But nothing gets rendered on my Page. 
I am not sure if I am rightly accessing the nested User object in Users Collection of JSON and its properties.
what am I missing.

Comment: It's possible I'm reading it wrong, but it looks like you're trying to loop through the Users level of the JSON, which isn't actually an array. It looks like the Users property has a couple of random properties, then another property `User` which holds the array of users

Comment: I declared users as an array in the code `$scope.users = [];`.what do you mean by its not an array?

Comment: Aah sorry, the `Users` level of the JSON data is not an array -> You have `"Users": {...}` - the data at this level is not an array. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah, could be how do we deal with these then?

Comment: I think this is what TypedSource was trying to mention below - instead of doing `angular.forEach(response.Users...` do `angular.forEach(response.Users.User` -> the key difference is the extra `.User` at the end. You've already tried that?

Comment: Also, when you say "Nothing gets rendered on my page" -> does the variable `TestValue` get rendered? I don't see any issues with the setup for that variable

Comment: Yes, testValue gets displayed.Yes, I tried response.Users.User but no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140205/discussion-between-radical-fanatic-and-programmerzzz).

Answer (score 2):

I've created plunker with your code and all I did to make it work is to change it to this:

```
$scope.Myfunc = function asdf() {
    $http.get('test.json').then(function(response) {
      $scope.users = [];
      angular.forEach(response.data.Users.User, function(value, key) {
        $scope.users.push(value);
      });
    });
  };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Fu1tCnhxSn9dgBXtTJ9r?p=preview

You must remember that `then` after http promise gets resolved receives an object that contains several values: status code, headers and `data` that will contain your data

Comment: This was the issue, FYI - adding `.data`

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is here

```
 $scope.users = [];
                angular.forEach(response.Users, function (value, key) {
                    $scope.users.push(value);
                });
```

try change to

```
$scope.users = response.data.Users
```

or you can change to

```
 $scope.users = [];
                    angular.forEach(response.data.Users, function (value, key) {
                        $scope.users.push(value);
                    });
```

Comment: this just gives list items equal to number of users returned by the service but no data yet..:(

Comment: @Programmerzzz in your html , try change to `k.user.WWID`

Comment: can not be. definitly is he has to access response.Users.User because here is the array he wants to access

Comment: @Programmerzzz dont change anything in html and in js try change to `response.data.Users.User` , it work well

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.forEach(response.Users.User, function (value, key) {
 $scope.users.push(value);
});
```

your array is nested so you have to call the array in the object

Comment: sure ur response is what you exprect to get and it's json object and not json string?

Comment: I think its a JSON string, you mean we need to parse it before we do the processing on it using forEach loop?

Comment: console.log(response) if it is displayed as object what you can expand, you dont need to parse. otherwhise JSON.parse(response) before the loop